# AT+VCID=1 is not enabling Caller Id on USR modem

Tags: linux, modem, caller-id

I'm testing a [USR 5637 USB modem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0013FDLM0). According to  [the USR docs](https://support.usr.com/support/5637/5637-ug/ref_data.html) I can query modem support for Caller Id with [`AT+VCID`](https://support.usr.com/support/5637/5637-ug/ref_data.html):

```
Debug: modem_write
Debug: Write 10: "AT+VCID=?\r"
Debug: modem_read
Debug: Read 24: "AT+VCID=?
(0-16)
OK"
```

The `0-16` is unusual because  [the manual states](https://support.usr.com/support/5637/5637-ug/ref_data.html) the values are `0, 1, 2`. I then go on to set to `1`, which [per the manual](https://support.usr.com/support/5637/5637-ug/ref_data.html) *`Enables formatted Caller ID`*:

```
Debug: modem_write
Debug: Write 10: "AT+VCID=1\r"
Debug: modem_read
Debug: Read 14: "AT+VCID=1
OK"
```

Later, when a call arrives, the Caller Id information is not presented by the USR modem. The Caller Id information should be presented between rings 1 and 2.

The same code works well with Conextant 93001-based modems, so I am fairly certain the code is correct. (Or mostly OK, with no obvious defect).

It looks like others have experienced similar problems (for example, [Caller ID detection -> US Robotics 56K?](http://nch.invisionzone.com/topic/19031-caller-id-detection-us-robotics-56k/) with a different product), but I don't see a solution.

Why is the USR modem not presenting the Caller Id information?

---

Here is the startup sequence I am using. It seems to follow the US Robotics manual.

```
init:
while (ATZ != OK)
  goto init

# gather modem info
ATI0
ATI1
ATI2
ATI3
ATI4

# query fax class
AT+FCLASS=?

# query compression
AT+VSM=?

# set caller id
AT+VCID=1

loop:
    # process data
    read_modem
    ...

    goto loop
```

---

Here is what  *`formatted Caller ID`* looks like on the Conexant modems. On the Conexant modems this appears between rings 1 and 2:

```
Debug: modem_read
Debug: Read 59: "DATE = 0302
TIME = 1601
NMBR = 6045551212
NAME = JOHN DOE"
```

---

Here is the initialization string Windows uses. It is taken from [USR5637Voice64bit.exe driver](https://www.usr.com/en-support/product/?prod=5637) download and the `usr5637_rv.inf` file:

```
AT
AT&F1E0Q0V1&C1&D2S0=0
```

When I tested it, the initialization string does not enable Caller Id, either.

Comment: I'm not a USR expert nit at least I am familiar with AT commands. Does the phone ring at least twice before picking up? If not, maybe you need to add ATS1=2   Also, what is your modem init string?

Comment: When intializing modems for dialup in my youth, I used AT&F&C1&D2  to initialize them - probably wont help, but worth a try?

Comment: @davidgo - Thanks. Modem init string is a soft reset with `ATZ`. After soft reset `&C1` and `&D2` are set. Also see pastebin at [USR Config after ATZ](https://pastebin.com/g9sJgcBM).

Comment: Id be surprised if it didnt hold true. I dont thonk there would have been much innovation after that the push to broadband was underway.

Comment: @davidgo - USR Technical Support could not tell me how to enable CID on their modems. I asked them for either (1) a description of the steps or (2) a C program to demonstrate it. I asked several times over a two week period during communications. USR simply ignored that request as if I did not write it. Their canned response was, "does it work on Windows with terminal program" even though I am working on Linux and OS X. (Apparently USR Support does not realize Microsoft stopped shipping the terminal program with Windows 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a while but here is the answer. The following three options must be set to get Caller ID information from the USR5367 modem:

```
init:
while (ATZ != OK)
  goto init

# set fax class
AT+FCLASS=8

# disable call waiting
AT+PCW=0

# set caller id
AT+VCID=1

loop:
    # process data
    read_modem
    ...

    goto loop
```

The Call Waiting feature has something to do with the Modem on Hold (MoH) feature of USR modems, and the ability of the modem to switch lines during a call. I don't quite understand what call waiting has to do with caller id, though.

In contrast, Conexant CX93001-based modems only need `AT+VCID=1`. And Conexant require `AT+FCLASS=0`; setting `+FCLASS` causes Caller ID to stop working. `+PCW` does not appear to make a difference; and Conexant works with `AT+PCW=2`.

---

If you need to detect Conexant vs USR modems at runtime, then use `ATI3`. The modem strings returned are:

Conexant:

```
Debug: modem_write
Debug: Write 7: "ATI3\r"
Debug: modem_read
Debug: Read 38: "ATI3
CX93001-EIS_V0.2013-V92

OK"
```

USR:

```
Debug: modem_write
Debug: Write 7: "ATI3\r"
Debug: modem_read
Debug: Read 48: "ATI3
U.S. Robotics 56K FAX USB V1.2.23

OK"
```

---

This may be helpful to someone programming a USR5367 modem... When Caller ID is functioning for the USR5367, the modem communicates Caller ID related messages with *"Data Link Escape"* (DLE) messages. DLE messages are signaled with character 0x10.

`RING` is communicated with `<DLE>+R` and Caller ID info with `<DLE>+X`. So ring is signaled with two bytes `0x10 0x52` (followed by `<CR><LF>`). Caller ID info is signaled with the two bytes `0x10 0x58 0x10` (followed by `<CR><LF>`). The Caller ID data follows `<DLE>+X` using name/value pairs, like `NAME=PASADENA     MD<CR><LF>` and `NMBR=4104394421<CR><LF>`. A full CallerID message would look like:

```
<DLE>+X<CR><LF>
NAME=PASADENA     MD<CR><LF>
NMBR=4104394421<CR><LF>
DATE=1106<CR><LF>
TIME=1425<CR><LF>
```

(And `<CR><LF>` is called the "trailer" in the manual and used as end-of-line as indicated by the `S3`and `S4` register parameters).

Comment: I got a Conexant modem and At first by running AT+VCID=1 it start to report number reliably but after few day when I back to working on my code it stopped working and never worked again. I don't know what was happened It just report ring. I try lots of tweaks and none of them worked. I really frustrated after two weeks of trying and fail. I thinks something inside mode failed or our local phone line provider change something!

Comment: this is current configuration dump:

https://gist.github.com/kingofnull/39454103e78c91dad2a2c3b9b79d3931